# Delete string from a double in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, double

I am sending data from arduino to c# and have a problem. The value I get from the serialread comes with an "\r" at the end of it, example: "19.42\r". I found a solution to delete the characters after my number by using Regex. But it also makes my double an integer. "19.42\r" becomes "1942". How can I delete my string but still keep the value as a double?

`line = Regex.Replace(line, @"[^\d]", string.Empty);`

Comment: If your goal is to simply remove the `\r` at the end, why go to the trouble of a regex? Why not use `Substring`?

Comment: why not ```"19.42\r".Replace("\r", string.Empty)``` ?

Comment: `line.Replace(@"\r", "")`

Comment: Use `line = line.TrimEnd();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to trim the whitespace from the end of the string.

Use

```
line = line.TrimEnd();
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/a83oKX)

If you need to actually *extract* a double number from a string with regex, use

```
var my_number = string.Empty;
var match = Regex.Match(line, @"[0-9]+\.[0-9]+");
if (match.Success) 
{   
    my_number = match.Value;
}
```

If the number can have no fractional part, use `@"[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+"` regex.

Comment: Also, if you just want to remove non-digit symbols at the end of the string, you may use `line = Regex.Replace(line, @"\D+$", "");`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string data = "19.42\r";
return data.Substring(0, data.Length - 1);
```

or even better

```
data.TrimEnd('\r')
```

Answer (score 0):

**if \r is fixed characters you want to remove**

```
string str = "awdawdaw\r";
str = str.replace("\r","");
```

**if \r is not fixed characters you want to remove**

```
string str = "awdawdaw\\";
str = str.Substring((str.Length - 2), 2);  \\will be removed
```

Comment: The OP clearly wants to remove just the `\r` characters and only at the end of the string.  Your code will remove `\r` wherever it occurs in the string.

Comment: yeah but I extended because may be in some case he needs something different